# playing mp3 audio file in firefox browser

Tags: audio

I have searched for various articles about playing mp3 files in firefox but no luck. 
I want something similar to this website for playing my audio files:
http://www.waatea603am.co.nz/podcasts

Can anyone tell me how is the audio files being played in the website. I want to do something similar. I cant figure out how it is being done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's the JavaScript that makes the links play sound:

http://www.waatea603am.co.nz/Resources/JavaScript/podcast-audio.js

It's basically using the HTML5 Audio element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var snd = new Audio("file.mp3"); // buffers automatically when created
    snd.play();
</script>
```

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio

Comment: You could also just serve the MP3 file, without the Javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a "programming" question, as much as a "Firefox configuration" question.

Personally:

- I don't really have any preferences of "media player" for Linux
- I simply use Windows media player for Windows
- Windows Media player comes built in with all recent versions of Windows
- Windows media is the default file association for .mp3 on all recent versions of Windows
- Consequently, Firefox automatically uses Windows Media player to play .mp3's

Here's more info:

- Issues:_Sound">http://kb.mozillazine.org/Mozilla_Suite_:*Issues*:_Sound
- http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-common-audio-and-video-issues

'Hope that helps .. PSM

PS:

Unfortunately, most commercial Internet radio stations seem to use Flash to broadcast audio streams.  Sigh...